Accessing cookie(s) inside a Chrome Browser Extension
I'm attempting to access a cookie from inside a Chrome Browser Extension.  The problem is that when I update the manifest.json to allow cookies, the Chrome Store rejects it due to cookies not being used in the code.
Clearly, the popup.js and the (fetched) PHP script rely upon accessing the cookie.  Any ideas?  Here's the manifest, and the popup.js scripts:
Manifest.json:
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "[Redacted]",
  "version": "1.5",
  "description": "[Redacted]",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "cookies"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "*://*.[Redacted].com/*"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icons/icon16.png",
      "48": "icons/icon48.png",
      "128": "icons/icon128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  }
}

Popup.js:

`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // Set or check the cookie first
  if (!getCookie('user_email')) {
    document.cookie = "user_email=new_trial_user; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";
  }

  // Query the active tab for its URL
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;
    var urlDisplay = document.getElementById('url-display');
    urlDisplay.innerHTML = '<span style="font-size: larger; font-weight: bold;">Analyzing...<br><br> ' + url + '</span>';

    // Send the URL to the server for processing
    fetch('https://[redacted].com/extract.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      body: 'input_text=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
      var formattedData = data.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
      urlDisplay.innerHTML = formattedData;
      urlDisplay.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'; // Visual feedback
    });
  });
});

// Helper function to retrieve a cookie value by name
function getCookie(name) {
  let cookieArray = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(let i = 0; i < cookieArray.length; i++) {
    let cookiePair = cookieArray[i].split('=');
    if(name === cookiePair[0].trim()) {
      return decodeURIComponent(cookiePair[1]);
    }
  }
  return null;
}`


I removed the "offending" cookie references in both manifest.json and the popup.js files, and just tried accessing with the associated php script.  It worked somewhat in Brave Browser, but not in the Chrome Browser.  Tried accepting all third party cookies.  No luck.


The cookie permission is for chrome.cookies API, not for document.cookie. 2) To access cookies of the tab you need to use a content script.

